# ¿Cómo hacer un stored procedure con el array $_GET?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Buen día, estoy realizando una página dinámica en php, que tiene en el index varios artículos, al darle clic a cualquier artículo, este, según su id, se carga en la página descripción, para obtener los datos, utiliza el siguiente código:

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
$resultado = $conexion -> query("SELECT * FROM productos WHERE IdProducto=".$_GET['id'])or die($conexion -> error);
if(mysqli_num_rows($resultado) > 0){
    $fila = mysqli_fetch_row($resultado);
```

Quiero hacer un Stored Procedure, pero no sé como hacerlo para que tome el valor del ID, ni como introducirlo en el query de PHP. Agradecería infinitamente si me pudiesen ayudar. Saludos.

Comment: ¿Qué te ha llevado a querer hacer un procedimiento almacenado? Porque como describes el caso, ya tienes todo lo que necesitas,

Comment: Requisitos, es para un proyecto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El procedimiento puede ser algo así:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE getItemId(IN id_prod INT(2))
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM productos
    WHERE IdProducto = id_prod;
END$$
DELIMITER
```

Llamarlo desde PHP con la función `CALL`

```
$sql = "CALL getItemId($_GET['id']);";
$resultado = $conexion->query($sql)or die($conexion -> error);
```

Aunque esto funciona, es muy inseguro por la forma en que recuperas tus variables, te sugiero revisar sobre inyección SQL y bindear los parámetros que recibes antes de ejecutarlos en una consulta.